# ruby: use hash as default value of another hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to use a hash as a bigger hash's default value. But I don't know how to set the inner hash's value through the outer hash.

```
h = Hash.new do 
  {:counter => 0}
end
h[:a][:counter] += 1
=> 1 
h[:a][:counter] += 1
=> 1
h[:a][:counter] += 1
=> 1 
h
=> {}
```

Uh, what's the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [initialize with a default value](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) of a hash:

```
h = Hash.new({:counter => 5})
```

Then you can follow the calling pattern in your example:

```
h[:a][:counter] += 1
 => 6 
h[:a][:counter] += 1
 => 7 
h[:a][:counter] += 1
 => 8
```

Alternatively you may want to intialize with a block so a new instance of the `:counter` hash is created every time you use a new key:

```
# Shared nested hash
h = Hash.new({:counter => 5})
h[:a][:counter] += 1
 => 6 
h[:boo][:counter] += 1
 => 7 
h[:a][:counter] += 1
 => 8 

# New hash for each default
n_h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {:counter => 5} }
n_h[:a][:counter] += 1
 => 6 
n_h[:boo][:counter] += 1
 => 6 
n_h[:a][:counter] += 1
 => 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def_hash={:key=>"value"}
another_hash=Hash.new(def_hash)
another_hash[:foo] # => {:key=>"value"}
```